# In Node.js, given a URL, how do I check whether its a jpg/png/gif?

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, mime-types, content-type

My current method is this:

```
var request = require('request');
var mime = require('mime');
var fs = require('fs');
var uri = 'http://www.sweetslyrics.com/images/img_gal/25646_christina-perri-213968.jpg';
request({
        'method':'GET',
        'uri': uri
},function(err, response,body){
    var tmp_path = '/tmp/123456';
    fs.writeFile(tmp_path, body, function(err) {
        console.log(mime.lookup(tmp_path));  //application/octet-stream ?????
    });
});
```

The image is obviously a picture, but `node-mime` says it's `application/octet-stream`. Why?

Note: 
- I do not want to rely on the Response Headers content-type, because based on my experience, sometimes those response headers are set incorrectly...and they do not determine the true file type. (that's why I save it to a file, and then have node-mime determine it for me!)

**I want to know the best way to determine if a file is an image, with 0 margin of error.**

Edit: I just realized that node-mime isn't "magic".  It just checks for the extension :( ...

Edit2: I found this: https://github.com/SaltwaterC/mime-magic

Comment: what's wrong with checking the last three characters of the uri?

Comment: note that if your going to fetch the file to check but not store it, it might be better to use a range request for the first few kilobytes rather than retrieving the whole file.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just read the first bytes of the stream, and check it for the so called "magic number".

> Magic numbers are the first bits of a file which uniquely identify the
> type of file.

For example:
-Every JPEG file begins with `ff d8` (hex).
-Every png file begins with a `89 50 4e 47`.
-There is a comprehensive table of magic numbers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

This way even if you have a file without extension you can still detect its type.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a node-js module that does this?

Comment: @TIMEX I haven't heard of any library to do that, but it won't take more than ten lines of code to implement such functionality. To get the magic number from the buffer just use `buffer.toString('hex',0,4);`. For a jpg file this function will return `ffd8ffe0`. Now you should just compare this string against the table I specified in the answer to get the extension and mime type.

Comment: there is imagemagick for nodejs. there you can check the format of the image. more info at http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html

Comment: what if I wrap a virus into image.jpg? would it still begin with `ff d8`?

Comment: [`image-type`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/image-type) (a wrapper of [`file-type`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type)) is a JS-only module which tests for a few common image types.

Comment: The link to the table returns a 403

Comment: @JacobSchneider link fixed.

Answer (score 12):

This code shows a working solution for the magic numbers approach (summary of the existing answers and information on https://github.com/request/request).

```
var request = require('request');
var url = "http://www.somedomain.com/somepicture.jpg";
var magic = {
    jpg: 'ffd8ffe0',
    png: '89504e47',
    gif: '47494638'
};
var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    encoding: null // keeps the body as buffer
};

request(options, function (err, response, body) {
    if(!err && response.statusCode == 200){
        var magigNumberInBody = body.toString('hex',0,4);
        if (magigNumberInBody == magic.jpg || 
            magigNumberInBody == magic.png ||
            magigNumberInBody == magic.gif) {

            // do something

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 3):

There are two modules that can help you achieve this:

https://github.com/SaltwaterC/mime-magic

https://github.com/bentomas/node-mime

Comment: The first uses the "file" command line utility on *nix OSes creating a sub-process for each query, the second uses and extension-mime dictionary

Comment: There's a third module, considering that you are dealing with images only: https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick

Comment: both links are not relevant any more

Answer (score 1):

In the intervening time since this question was first asked, mime-magic has become unsupported and its author recommends the use of [mmmagic](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic).  I don't know what happened to node-mime, the link above is a 404.  I found the following article which discusses the topic as well: https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/mime

Answer (score 0):

i developped this code and i test it and it work for me you can use it

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var http = require('http').Server(app).listen(80)
var upload = require('express-fileupload')
app.use(upload())
        app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
            res.sendFile(__dirname+"/file.html")
        })
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
        var options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: req.files.filename,
            encoding: null
        }
        if (req.files) {
         if (req.files.filename.data.toString('hex',0,4) ==  '89504e47' || req.files.filename.data.toString('hex',0,4) == 'ffd8ffe0' || req.files.filename.data.toString('hex',0,4) == '47494638' ) {
            var file = req.files.filename
            filename = file.name
            file.mv('./upload/'+filename,(err)=>{
               if (err) {
                   console.log('small err')
               } else {
                res.send('DONE')
               }
            })
         } else {
             console.log('it not an image')
         }
}
})
```