# Using FileReader to read cloud images in Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, filereader

I have the following javascript which provides an image upload button and displays the image:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();            
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#target').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

The full jsfiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/6NXwv/

This code works on every mobile browser I've tried except for the stock Android browser. Specifically images only fail to load if they are stored remotely but appear in the gallery (for example synced facebook or picasa images). Now I know FileReader is only for LOCAL files however chrome browser, opera, and firefox mobile have no issues.

I checked the FileReader error code, it appears that gallery images from facebook/picasa return NOT_FOUND_ERR:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileError

If this is a case of FileReader not able to read remote files why does it work in all other mobile browsers?

I can't find anyone else having this exact issue, everything I google keeps returning this result:
[Issue with stock Browser picking photos from Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702396/issue-with-stock-browser-picking-photos-from-gallery)

However the mime-type appears to be detected correctly. The mime-type shows up and the filename shows the correct name but the actual data isn't there (also File.size reports '0'). I've been able to recreate this on the stock android browser on 4.4 and 4.3. Haven't tested older versions.

In short when selecting photos via the gallery, local files and new images taken with the camera load correctly but remote facebook/picasa files (on 4.4 at least they have little fb/picasa icons on their thumbnails in the gallery) do not load. Only occurs in stock browser.

Answer (score 0):

The error you face have 2 explanation.

1. First explanation is that the files "Images" that you tried to read with HTML5 API FileReader are looked or on use by other applications "like Facebook or Picasa" and in this case you can do nothing about it from js unless you have physical access to the hardware "Phone".
2. second explanation which is more likely is some browsers can't fire the event onload of FileReader because they are not fully supporting this HTML5 API. you can read more about this in caniuse website. And that can be solve by changing the event **onload** to **onloadend**.

here is how your code should be :

```
var reader = new FileReader(); 
reader.onloadend = function () { 
    console.log(reader.result); 
}; 
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

here is example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/el_houssine_laidi/v7w4r8kf/1/)

here is Demo: [Demo FileReader Html5](https://www.xn--mgbq7clf5a.com/helpCommunity/FileReader-Html5/)

Comment: you can download the demo from [here](https://github.com/elhoussinelaidi/FileReaderHtml5)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input id="fileinput" name="arquivo[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" onchange="FileDetails()"/>
    <var id="file_List"></var>
    <button type="button" onclick="Click()">Click Me!</button>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    // simple routine to put content of file input files into memory
    G_Array         = [];
    G_Cont_Upload   = 0;
    function Click() 
    {
        var a = 1;                                      // this is only to check the content of global variable as google chrome does not stop inside f_ReadFile
    }
    function FileDetails() 
        {
        var file_arr = [];
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") 
            {
            var files = $('#fileinput')[0].files; 
            var reader  = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                {
                var FileDet = files[i];

                var name    = FileDet.name;
                var Size    = FileDet.size;
                var Obj     = {Name: FileDet.name, SizeInicial : FileDet.size};
                G_Array.push(Obj);

                reader[i]   = new FileReader();

                function f_ReadFile(e)
                    {
                    var content = e.target.result;
                    G_Array[G_Cont_Upload].SizeAtual = content.length;
                    G_Array[G_Cont_Upload].Content   = content;           // content base 64
                    G_Cont_Upload++;
                    }
                reader[i].onload = f_ReadFile;
                reader[i].readAsDataURL(FileDet);
                }
            } 
        else 
            {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
            }
        }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: This answer should be edited to explain how it solves the question.