# Determine if a file is really an image in express/node.js

Tags: node.js, express

How can I check if the file uploaded on my server is really an image? Not just a file with (jpg,png,gif) extension just to make it as "an image" file. I created an image compression service using imagemin, but I'm afraid if the uploaded file is really an image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Node.js, given a URL, how do I check whether its a jpg/png/gif?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473703/in-node-js-given-a-url-how-do-i-check-whether-its-a-jpg-png-gif)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used the mmmagic module for this, it discovers mime types:
[mmmagic on Github](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic)

Comment: Just a question, when I try to upload "invalid.png" to my server (though, it was just created on notepad and just change its extension) will the mime type will be change to image/png or just, say, text/plain ?

Comment: coz if mime type will be image/png then the module is not useful then

Comment: My own use case was to determine true PDF files from html output that was given a PDF extension, and it worked just fine.  If you take a look at the Github repo, you'll see the module works by inspecting the file data, not simply by checking an extension.

Comment: Oh yeah. I read the description. I will try this now. I will accept your answer later if this will work on my case

Answer (score 3):

Another option is https://github.com/sindresorhus/image-type. Looks like mmmagic relies on libmagic which is a C lib and might be a lot to pull in...

Answer (score 1):

Mime types are not useful.
Try magic numbers or purely try to open the file.
Read with link for more details.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8475542/1979882

http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html#Image

Comment: mmmagic does exactly this, reads the binary data of the file, looks for the identification bytes, and turns that into information about the file, including mime type.  It's even mentioned in the stackoverflow link you provided.