# Unable to add image validation using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs and using expressjs framework,Right now i am trying to upload image using Api but i want two things

```
1) i want add "height,width" validation on image
2) if image extension is not "jpg,png,gif" then error message should display
```

Here is my current code

```
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
 filename: function (req, file, callback) {
     var sizeOf = require('image-size');
        const originalname = file.originalname;
        const dimensions = `sizeOf(./uploads/${originalname})`;
        console.log(dimensions.width, dimensions.height); // GETTING UNDEFINED UNDEFINED IN CONSLOLE
            
        const fileExt = originalname.split(".").pop();
        const excatName = originalname.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".");
        callback(null, excatName + "-" + Date.now().toString() + "." + fileExt);
      },
});
//var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).any('file');
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('userPhoto');
 const uploadavatar = function (req, res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file." + err);
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing backticks will do the trick

```
 const dimensions = `sizeOf(./uploads/${originalname})`;
```

To

```
const dimensions = sizeOf(`./uploads/${originalname}`);
```

Comment: and what about 2nd point ? how can i validate image extension ?

Comment: your code is not working , giving me following error


Unexpected token '.'

Comment: You can check the starting bytes of the buffer. I believe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473703/in-node-js-given-a-url-how-do-i-check-whether-its-a-jpg-png-gif) will help you.

Comment: @prabhatmohal I forgot to re-arrange the backticks, it should work now

Comment: now i am getting error , "no such file or directory open filepath"